# ORA-22905 - While using DBMS_SQL.Number_Table for Table Operator

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

All,

Here is a simplified version of what I am attempting to accomplish.  Instead of declaring my own type, I used the Number_Table type from the dbms_sql package.
First I created a simple test table:

```
CREATE TABLE collect_test(id NUMBER(38), other_info VARCHAR2(5));
```

Then, populated the table with a small amount of data:

```
INSERT INTO collect_test
SELECT rownum, chr(rownum+60)
FROM dual
CONNECT BY rownum <= 10;
```

Finally, I attempt to use PL/SQL to select some rows into a collection then use that collection to delete rows from the table:

```
DECLARE
  l_tIDList DBMS_SQL.Number_Table;
BEGIN
  SELECT ct.id
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_tIDList
  FROM collect_test ct
  WHERE mod(ct.id, 2) = 0;

  DELETE FROM (SELECT ct.id
               FROM collect_test ct
               INNER JOIN table(l_tIDList) ids ON ct.id = ids.column_value);

  ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

However, when I run this PL/SQL block I receive these errors:

```
ORA-06550: line 11, column 33:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type 
ORA-06550: line 11, column 27:
PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
ORA-06550: line 9, column 3: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

In all the other questions/articles I have found it seems like the coder was either trying to use a local type or forgetting to BULK COLLECT.  I appreciate any suggestions you may have.

N.B.: I realize that I can do this specific functionality using a single DELETE statement.  My actual scenario is more complicated and can't be done with a single statement.

Comment: _ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item._  `dbms_sql.number_table` is a non-nested table type, i.e. it's not a nested table.

Comment: You delete from a collection using the [`yourcollection.delete` collection method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/collection-method.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish, there are two things which are wrong with your pl/sql block.

- You can use the `TABLE()` function on the variables of collection
  types defined in the schema and not on those defined locally
- The way you are running your DML ( delete ) statement is wrong, it throws the error `

> ORA-22841: DML on PL/SQL collections not supported.

So, create a collection `TYPE` in your schema and declare a collection of that type in your PL/SQL block and for your delete use an `IN` condition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE idlisttable as TABLE OF NUMBER;

DECLARE l_tidlist idlisttable;

BEGIN
    SELECT ct.id BULK collect
    INTO l_tidlist
    FROM collect_test ct
    WHERE MOD(ct.id, 2) = 0;

    DELETE
    FROM collect_test ct
    WHERE ct.id IN (
            SELECT ids.column_value
            FROM TABLE (l_tidlist) ids
            );

    ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

`

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It appears that most of the issue had to due with dbms_sql.number_table being an associative array.  Once I declared my own type I was able to get the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this using a cursor and it worked for me. Please try as below.

```
    DECLARE
      l_tIDList DBMS_SQL.Number_Table;
      CURSOR c
      IS
        SELECT ct.id FROM collect_test ct WHERE mod(ct.id, 2) = 0;
    BEGIN
      OPEN c;
      LOOP
    FETCH c bulk collect INTO l_tIDList;
    forall i IN 1 .. l_tIDList.count
    DELETE FROM collect_test t WHERE t.id = l_tIDList(i);
    EXIT
  WHEN c%notfound;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
  CLOSE c;
END ;
/
```

Comment: I appreciate that you are avoiding the context switching by using the FORALL statement.  However, with my actual use case there are over 2 million rows.  What are your thoughts on FORALL still creating 2 million DML statements vs the join to collection?

Comment: The collection is already fetched and stored.. So for records > million I would certainly use bulk collect and delete.